# Merge sort in haskell goes in infinite loop

Tags: haskell

Hi everybody I am attempting to reproduce merge sort in haskel, here is my code:

```
-- merge
merge :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge [] [] = []
merge xs [] = xs
merge [] ys = ys
merge (x:xs) (y:ys)
  | x <= y = x:(merge xs (y:ys))
  | otherwise = y:(merge (x:xs) ys)

-- split
splitIn2 :: (Ord a) => [a] -> ([a],[a])
splitIn2 [] = ([],[])
splitIn2 xs = splitAt ((length xs `div` 2)+1) xs

-- msort
msort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
msort [] = []
msort [x] = [x]
msort (xs) = merge (msort as) (msort bs)
    where (as,bs) = splitIn2 xs
```

It compiles on ghc, and it works for:

```
*Main> msort([])
[]
*Main> msort([1])
[1]
```

However it doesnt do its job properly because it starts too loop infinitely (at least this is what I thought) and it doesnt print anything.

I think it is because I dont remove elements from the lists like I did in other recursive experiment, any suggestion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that when `length xs == 2`,

```
(length xs `div` 2) + 1
= (2 `div` 2) + 1
= 1 + 1
= 2
```

and `splitAt 2 xs` returns `(xs, [])`. Since the first list is still of length `2`,
`msort` will try to `splitIn2` it down again in an infinite loop.

To solve this, you can simply get rid of the `+1`; it's completely unnecessary. You can
also eliminate the special case for the empty list, since `splitAt 0 [] = ([], [])`.

```
splitIn2 xs = splitAt (length xs `div` 2) xs
```

Answer (score 2):

```
*Main> splitIn2 [1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 6]
([1,2,3,0],[5,6])
```

And after small change (deleting `+1` ):

```
splitIn2 xs = splitAt ((length xs `div` 2)) xs
```

It works:

```
*Main> splitIn2 [1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 6]
([1,2,3],[0,5,6])
*Main> msort [1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 6]
[0,1,2,3,5,6]
```

Comment: Ok I dont understand why it is not working also with the +1, any explanation?

Comment: @graphtheory92 The problem is with the 2-element list. And hammar explained this above.